# list.index() does not find existing element

Tags: python

I have a nested list of binary values `(0,1)` as integers.

I know we cannot recursively descend into a multidimensional list to find the element so i put a loop to get a single list.

And then calling `list.index(0)` it finds the correct index of 0's but when i call `list.index(1)` it returns a value error. I am mainly looking for an explanation not a solution.

Code:

```
def getA(a):
    b = 0
    m = [] 
    for j in range(a):
        b = b+j
    for x in range(b+1):
        m.append(getR(x))
    for z in m:
        print(z.index(1))  # Throws ValueError: 1 is not in list
```

However printing z:

```
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
 [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
 [0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
 [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
 [1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

and finally printing z.index(0):

```
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 1
 1
 1
 2
```

Comment: can you post code of getR, and some example of input

Comment: There is no 1 in the first line. list.index is *supposed* to raise ValueError in this case.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

list.index(1) returns a value error because your first list ([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]) does not have a '1' in it. You'd see a similar response if you tried list.index(2)

Comment: Thanks , it makes sense

Answer (score 1):

This is how the method `index` works. If it does not find value in the list it raises exception `Value Error`.

Since each list contains `0` it works fine and returns the first index for `0` in each list.

But for example, the first list does not contain `1` and that is why it raises an exception.

You can add `1` to the first list and see that exception is no longer raised.

Comment: Thanks , it makes sense